# Load Images Only on Focus/Target

Tags: jquery, image, load

I have around 300+ images sized 50-100kb each. The server is taking so much time to load all images on page load. How can i load images like on google books?

Comment: do you have scroll kind of stuff like jcaraousal , for images or showing all 300 images in one page??

Answer (score 1):

It's called "lazy loading". [Lazy Loading Of Images – Resources You Need](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/lazy-loading-of-images-resources-you-need/)
 shows how to do this using most popular JS frameworks.

For example, in jQuery you can do this with the [Lazy load plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload):

HTML:

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.lazyload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
<img class="lazy" src="img/grey.gif" data-original="img/example.jpg"
     width="640" heigh="480">
```

JS:

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload();
```